# Gradient Ricci solitons on surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Ramos and Berstein-Mettler have provided classification of two dimensional gradient Ricci solitons (even admitting singularities).

Is the problem of whether all two dimensional solitons are gradient still open in the smooth case (if not how about the singular case)? I have not found an answer or counter example anywhere ...